# Yii CDbCriteria- Query using IN

Tags: php, yii

What is the equivalent CDbCriteria method or properties if 
i want to query this way

```
select * from tbl_data where id in(2,3,6,8)
```

Im not sure as to which property to use though.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Try This

```
$condInArr = array(2,3,6,8);
$Criteria = new CDbCriteria();
$Criteria->addInCondition('id', $condInArr);
$List = TblData::model()->findAll($Criteria);
```